# Para que serve a NSLayoutConstraint "Aspect Ratio"?

Tags: ios, swift

Olá,

Desde que comecei a trabalhar com o AutoLayout, não achei nada que explicasse como/para que funciona a `NSLayoutConstraint` Aspect Ratio. Mesmo na documentação da Apple não encontrei nada que ajudasse a entender.

Alguém tem um exemplo para compartilhar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei formulando a pergunta em inglês, a resposta foi bastante útil: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123670/for-what-should-i-use-the-aspect-ratio-nslayoutconstraint

**UPDATE**

Explicação em português, traduzida da resposta dada:

> *Eu tenho um exemplo de como manter um quadrado centralizado em todos os dispositivos e orientações de tela.*
>
> *As constantes são configuradas no IB, mas você pode também fazê-lo pelo código. De qualquer forma, o objetivo aqui é explicar como priorizar as constantes de margem para fazer com que o AutoLayout saiba o que ele deve quebrar e quando. O que mantém o quadrado como ele está é a sua proporção (aspect ratio) - ele é 1:1. Se fosse um retângulo, mude para 2:1 (ou 1:2, dependendo da sua necessidade).*
>
> *Quando você compreender estas duas partes (priorização e proporção), a última parte são os valores das margens - Eu configurei como 10 pontos, o que significa que o quadrado terá 10 pontos de margem no seu menor eixo. Se o dispositivo for um iPad Pro 12.9", você terá um quadrado bem largo. Se este mesmo dispositivo for um iPhone SE, você terá, em contrapartida, um quadrado menor. Independente da situação, você terá uma margem de 10 pontos. Aumente a margem para 50 e o quadrado ficará relativamente menor. De qualquer jeito aqui, o importante é que você sempre terá uma proporção de 1:1, esta view sempre será um quadrado..*

**Conclusão**

A `NSLayoutConstraint` **Aspect Ratio** é a constante relacionada à **proporção** da `UIView` em questão.